# Сетевая библиотека для C#

Tags: c#, сеть

Хотелось бы найти сетевую библиотеку для C# TCP/IP для создания многопоточных серверов. Хотелось, чтобы передача данных осуществлялась с помощью пакетов. Можно было бы принимать данные как синхронно, так и асинхронно и работать с каждым клиентом отдельно. Также хотелось бы чтобы пакеты сериализовались в BSON или JSON.

Пробовал реализовать что-то свое, но получилось криво и почему-то пакеты иногда теряются и сбивается весь цикл чтения и парсинга пакетов. Для Java есть подобные библиотеки, а вот для .NET найти не могу. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Может проще заюзать WebSocket'ы?

Comment: Вы хотите написать библиотеку для организации многопоточных TCP серверов, которые будут обмениваться данными с клиентами в формате BSON или JSON? Для чего вам нужна эта библиотека? Чтобы использовать её в своей приложении?

Comment: Да, хочу сделать собственный чат

Comment: Библиотека [SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) - то, что доктор прописал (лучше на английском читать, если знаете язык). Также можно быстро на [WCF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application) сваять.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотек таких я лично не знаю. Возможно, они и есть, но толку от них было бы немного. Такие вещи реализуются самостоятельно. Используйте потоковые сокеты.

Создаёте [Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx), привязываете к локальной конечной точке (метод [Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind(v=vs.110).aspx)), указываете количество входящих соединений (метод [Listen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen(v=vs.110).aspx), -1 для неограниченного количества), принимаете входящие соединения и обрабатываете каждое в отдельном потоке. Что касается данных пакета, я думаю сами найдёте способ представления данных в нужном формате. Пусть будет метод, который перед отправкой всё вам завернёт в BSON или JSON, сериализует и пустит в сокет (десериализует при приёме).

Значит чат я бы на вашем месте организовал так:

1. Идентифицировал бы клиента и заносил бы его в словарь сопоставляя его id ссылку на объект сокета
2. При отправке сообщения, определял бы кому оно предназначено, вытаскивал бы сокет нужного пользователя из словаря по id и отправлял бы ему это сообщение
3. В качестве словаря посоветую использовать [асинхронные вещи](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx), иначе будут проблемы

Если речь шла бы о промышленных масштабах, то нужно продумать ещё и алгоритм распределения нагрузки (но это уже отдельная тема).

**UPD:** На счёт того, что вы теряете пакеты - да, это может быть (так уж устроены сокеты). Советую почитать спецификацию по winsock. Сам встречался с такой проблемой. Решил в итоге расширить размер входного буфера сокета ([Socket.ReceiveBufferSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx)) и создать что-то типа своего буфера (отдельный поток, который читает все данные с сокета, как только они там появляются ([Socket.Poll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll(v=vs.110).aspx)), и копирует в мой буфер - решение рабочее, но такое себе наверное (мне лень было тогда вникать)).